# Can imines be catalytically hydrogenated?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Can imines be catalytically hydrogenated? According to the DEA this appears to be possible. However I cannot find any other references to catalytic hydrogenation of imines anywhere else.

[image]

http://thedea.org/synthesis.html

Comment: Interesting to know why they use catalytic hydrog that requires some more expertise for the ambitious Walter White wannabe (handling gas cylinders, getting hold of one, getting hold of the catalyst) when simply $\ce {NaBH_4}$ should do the trick

Comment: @K_P Once you move from reaction with 1-10 mmol of costly source to reactions of 1-10 mol of cheap resource the use of costly reducers, like $\ce{NaBH4}$ becomes questionable at best. Despite common misconception, such works still happen.

Comment: @permeakra ... why not use Na(CN)BH4?

Comment: @Dissenter Because it costs much more than hydrogen gas. It is easier to use, but at larger scale the cost becomes significant enough to move to cheaper alternatives.

Comment: @permeakra Sure hydrogen is cost effective but I was not talking about professional labs. I assumed that for an amateur (the page linked looks like it is targeting this kind of group) it would be easier to find and handle sodium borohydride than a hydrogen cylinder and catalyst. I'm sure they can recover their shortfall selling this kind of product

Answer (score 2):

Yes, imines can be catalytically hydrogenated. Chapter 8 of Nishimura's *The Handbook of Heterogeneous Catalytic Hydrogenation for Organic Syntheses* is "Hydrogenation of Imines, Oximes, and Related Compounds" and gives several examples to work with.

The most analogous example in the chapter to your pictured reaction is Archer et al.'s preparation of 3α-(2-diethylaminoethyl)-aminotropane, wherein tropinone was condensed with N,N-diethylethylenediamine to give the imine, which was then catalytically hydrogenated at between room temperature and 50 °C over platinum oxide or Adams catalyst with 60-70% yield.

[Archer, et al. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1957**, *79*, 4194](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01572a056)

Answer (score 0):

Several methods on the reduction of imines are outlined on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogenation_of_carbon%E2%80%93nitrogen_double_bonds). Another method using catalytic hydrogenation is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imine#Imine_reductions).

Comment: Can you summarize what's at the links in the body of the answer, please.

Comment: @jonsca I thought somebody would mention that. There are more than 10 reactions on the web page and since Wikipedia is unlikely to disappear (although the page might get moved), there is enough information (i.e. reduction of imines) for anyone to search Wikipedia and find it.

Comment: I would agree that Wikipedia won't likely move anytime soon, but you never know.  Anyway, just adding *something*, even if you put, for example, "including palladium and ruthenium catalysis methods" or something to that effect makes it more self-contained and gives someone some keywords to search on to find a new link if that one went bad.  I realize it's too time and space consuming to list out all the information, so I'm certainly not expecting a whole laundry list.